# Node.js Sequelize ManyToMany relations producing incorrect SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem with sequelize ManyToMany relations.

Here are my models...

```
var db = {

    players: sequelize.define('players', {
        name: Sequelize.STRING
    }),

    teams: sequelize.define('teams', {
        name: Sequelize.STRING
    }),   


    init: function() {

        this.players.hasMany(this.teams, {joinTableName: 'teams_has_players'});
        this.teams.hasMany(this.players, {joinTableName: 'teams_has_players'});

        this.players.sync();
        this.teams.sync();

    }

};
```

Here's the find

```
db.players.findAll({
    where:      {team_id: 1},
    include:    ['teams']
}).success(function(results) {
    // print the results
});
```

The above find will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    players . *,
    teams.name AS `teams.name`,
    teams.id AS `teams.id`
FROM
    players
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    teams_has_players ON teams_has_players.player_id = players.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    teams ON teams.id = teams_has_players.team_id
WHERE
    players.team_id = '1';
```

What appears to be wrong with this is that the WHERE statement should be `WHERE teams.team_id = '1'`

Where am I going wrong with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm actually everything looks quite OK-ish. `db.players.findAll` with `where: { team_id: 1 }` should create a query with `WHERE players.team_id = '1'`. That's perfectly expected. Also, you `teams` won't have a `team_id` but an `id` instead. However, there is a good chance that `include` is broken atm.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it wasn't a bug, i've changed the find to...              db.teams.findAll({
            where:      {id: req.params.team_id},
            include:    ['players']
        }).success(function(results) {
            res.json(results);
        });             and it works as expected. Thanks for sequelize Sascha, just wish there was more documentation.

Comment: yeah many things have to be improved. if spare time would just be enough to do everything at once :)